# error in generating end point client library

Tags: android, entity, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to add a new method in the endpoint class for an entity. However when I right click on my app engine project to generate end point client library, eclipse throw message stating that generating end point library has thrown errors. Below is the code I have added in the endpoint library for my entity. Can anyone please suggest what is wrong here.

```
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<UserTable> getUserTableByEmail(String email) {
        EntityManager mgr = null;
        List<UserTable> execute = null;
        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select n from UserTable n where n.emailAddress = :emailAddress");
            query.setParameter("emailAddress", email);
            execute = (List<UserTable>) query.getResultList();
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return execute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated working code below for adding my own endpoint method with my custom query.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "getUserTableByEmail")
public CollectionResponse<UserTable> getUserTableByEmail(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit,
        @Named ("emailAddres") String email) {

    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<UserTable> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select n from UserTable n where n.emailAddress = '"+email+"'");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<UserTable>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (UserTable obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<UserTable> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}
```